# PhP & MySQL WHERE Syntax

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, insert

There is a registration interface where you must enter your billing information after logging in. 
The goal is to record the entered data in the MySQL database and update the "billable" value to "1", however I get a syntax error.

The code is (PhP 7.3):

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('location: login.php');
    exit();
}

include_once('dbconnect.php');

$username = $_SESSION["username"];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    if ($row['billable'] == 0) {

        $error = false;
        if(isset($_POST['btn-updatedetails'])) {

        $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['firstname']);
        $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['lastname']);
        $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['phone']);
        $company = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['company']);
        $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['country']);
        $county = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['county']);
        $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['city']);
        $street = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['street']);
        $postcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['postcode']);

        if(empty($firstname)) {
            $error = true;
            $errorFirstname = 'This field cannot be left blank.';
        }    

        if(empty($lastname)) {
            $error = true;
            $errorLastname = 'This field cannot be left blank.';
        } 

        if(empty($phone)) {
            $error = true;
            $errorPhone = 'This field cannot be left blank.';
        }  

        if(empty($country)) {
            $error = true;
            $errorCountry = 'This field cannot be left blank.';
        } 

        if(empty($county)) {
            $error = true;
            $errorCounty = 'This field cannot be left blank.';
        } 

        if(empty($city)) {
            $error = true;
            $errorCity = 'This field cannot be left blank.';
        } 

        if(empty($street)) {
            $error = true;
            $errorStreet = 'This field cannot be left blank.';
        } 

        if(empty($postcode)) {
            $error = true;
            $errorPostcode = 'This field cannot be left blank.';
        } 

        if(!$error){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, phone, company, country, county, city, street, postcode) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$phone', '$company', '$country', '$county', '$city', '$street', '$postcode') WHERE username = '$username' AND UPDATE users SET billable='1' WHERE username = '$username'";
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
                $successMsg = 'Success!';
            }else{
                echo 'Error '.mysqli_error($conn);
            }

        }

    }

        ?>
        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" autocomplete="off">
        Firstname:
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"><br>
        Lastname:
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"><br>
        Phone:
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"><br>
        Company (optional):
        <input type="text" name="company" id="company"><br>
        Country:
        <input type="text" name="country" id="country"><br>
        County:
        <input type="text" name="county" id="county"><br>
        City:
        <input type="text" name="city" id="city"><br>
        Street:
        <input type="text" name="street" id="street"><br>
        Postcode:
        <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode"><br>

        <input type="submit" name="btn-updatedetails">
        </form>

        <?php


} else {
        echo "<3";
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

This page returns the following error:

```
Error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE username = 'Erik' AND UPDATE users SET billable='1' WHERE username = 'Erik' at line 1
```

MySQL database:

[image: sql database]

Where did I make a mistake?

Thank you in advance for your answer! 
Have a nice day!

Comment: why are you doing this? `UPDATE users SET billable='1' WHERE username = '$username'"`

Comment: @Regolith same question.

Comment: you dont need `where` in insert statement

Comment: Okay. I deleted the first WHERE. The current code: `$sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, phone, company, country, county, city, street, postcode) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$phone', '$company', '$country', '$county', '$city', '$street', '$postcode') AND UPDATE users SET billable='1' WHERE username = '$username'";` Now I'm getting the following error: "Error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND UPDATE users SET billable='1' WHERE username = 'Erik'' at line 1 "

Comment: I suppose you understand you can directly INSERT the billable property at 1 ? Or use default value in your schema. Why update after ?

Comment: multiple statements need to be separated by a `;`, not an `AND`

Comment: I deleted the "AND" tag and the error remains unchanged with so many differences: `..the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE users SET billable='1' WHERE username = 'Erik'' at line 1 `

Comment: don't just delete the `AND`, _replace_ it with `;`. Apart from that, for multi queries you need to use `multi_query()` instead of `mysqli_query()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made the changes, but the error is indefinite.

Comment: try to move the update statement to the insert (as proposed by @VincentDecaux ), meaning setting `billable='1'` in the insert statement already. leave out the update statement afterwards completely and use the basic `mysql_query` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a `SELECT` to start with so I don't see why you want to `INSERT` another row for the same user. I think you just want to do a single `UPDATE` as such:

```sql
UPDATE users 
SET
    firstname = '$firstname',
    lastname = '$lastname',
    phone = '$phone',
    company = '$company',
    country = '$country',
    county = '$county',
    city = '$city',
    street = '$street',
    postcode = '$postcode',
    billable = 1
WHERE username = '$username'
```